# Add a class to anchor with li class already "current"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I have been Trying to figure this out for some time now. I have a navigation where the list item gets a class of "active" when on that page. I need to also give the anchor of those list items each a unique class. So my code is:

Application_helper

```
def link_to_with_current_class(name, options)
  if current_page?(options)
    content_tag :li, link_to(h(name), options), :class => "current"
  else
    content_tag :li, link_to(h(name), options)
  end   
end
```

Navigation

```
<ul id="nav">
      <%= link_to_with_current_class "work", home_path %>
      <%= link_to_with_current_class "about", about_path %>
      <%= link_to_with_current_class "contact", contact_path %>
    </ul>
```

This Generates

```
<ul id="nav">
      <li class="current"><a href="/">work</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I need it to generate

```
<ul id="nav">
      <li class="current"><a **class="work"** href="/">work</a></li>
      <li><a **class="about"** href="/about">about</a></li>
      <li><a **class="contact"** href="/contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I have tried this many ways but everything i try just breaks it. Any help on this issue would be much appreceatied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it might work:

```
def link_to_with_current_class(name, options)
  if current_page?(options)
    content_tag :li, link_to(h(name), options, :class => name), :class => "current"
  else
    content_tag :li, link_to(h(name), options, :class => name)
  end   
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That would only add a class name to a list item when it was not "current". I need to add a class to the anchor when it is "current"

Comment: I think i miss understood that code now that i try it again it works perfectly... Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Great, glad it helped.  Please consider accepting this as the answer.